# QlikView And Sense. Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: qlikview, cyrillic, qliksense

I'm working for a Bulgarian company and they use the Cyrillic alphabet. The Cyrillic characters are now showing as `?????` in QlikView and also in QlikSense. Does anyone know how to make this show properly?

Comment: What are your regional settings?

Comment: My PC is in Dutch. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: Might be. QV and QS are relying on regional setting. Try and set Control Panel --> Change display language --> Administrative --> Change system locale --> and pick Bulgarian there. You might need to reboot Windows after this.

Comment: Don't they know about Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Bulgarian people will not be happy about that but Cyrillic problem is fixed by selecting in Windows Regional settings option "Install Files for East Asian languages" (in older Windows version). In Windows 10 should be enough to add Bulgarian language.